# Empty mutable array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

How do i empty my mutable array ?

Thanks

Mason Soiza
([web design derby](http://soizastudios.co.uk/web-design-derby.html))

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
[yourArray removeAllObjects];
```